# Group seperated counting values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have following df

```
     A   B
0    1   10
1    2   20
2    NaN 5
3    3   1
4    NaN 2
5    NaN 3
6    1   10
7    2   50
8    Nan 80
9    3   5
```

Consisting of repeating sequences from 1-3 seperated by a variable number of NaN's.I want to groupby each this sequences from 1-3 and get the minimum value of column B within these sequences.

Desired Output something like:

```
     B_min
0    1
6    5
```

Many thanks beforehand

draj

Comment: post you written code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is first remove rows by missing values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), then use [`GroupBy.cummin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummin.html) by helper `Series` created by compare `A` for equal by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), last data cleaning to one column `DataFrame`:

```
df = (df.dropna(subset=['A'])
       .groupby(df['A'].eq(1).cumsum())['B']
       .min()
       .reset_index(drop=True)
       .to_frame(name='B_min'))
print (df)
   B_min
0      1
1      5
```

Comment: Thanks! I also was playing around with dropna first but I lack knowledge of such helper funcs like .eq(). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to `df.groupby()` and apply `min()`. Is this what you are expecting?

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].min()
```

Output:

```
A
1      10
2      20
3       1
Nan    80
```

If you don't want the `NaN`s in your group you can drop them using `df.dropna()`

```
df.dropna().groupby('A')['B'].min()
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, it’s not the desired output. Thanks anyways!